# convert flat information into multidimentional array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a table I am getting data from that creates a list of items.

The data looks like this:

```
Menu1,Header
Menu2,MenuItem
Menu3,MenuItem
Menu4,MenuItem
Menu5,MenuItem
Menu6,Header
Menu7,MenuItem
Menu8,MenuItem
Menu9,MenuItem
Menu10,MenuItem
...
```

My array needs to look like this:

```
MenuHeader -> MenuItem
           -> MenuItem
           -> MenuItem

MenuHeader -> MenuItem
           -> MenuItem
           -> MenuItem
```

ANy ideas?

Comment: Where is the data coming from, a csv file, web page?

Comment: From a table in MySql Database

Comment: You can connect to MySQL using PHP, write your query, and output it to a PHP array. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: THat what i dont know how to do :-) Write the code to construct the array that would give me the results i am after.

Comment: Can you provide the table names/data, or what your MySQL tables look like?

Comment: Table consists of the following columns:

id,title,type

Comment: How are you associating the MenuItems to the MenuHeaders in the database?

Comment: That is why i posted here as i am not associating the MenuItems to the MenuHeaders.

Comment: If they're not associated in the database, how do you expect to link them reliably in PHP? just go sequentially based off ids?

Comment: Well that is what I am asking :-) Is it possible via an array or something?

Comment: You can do it, but it's far from ideal. It basically negates the point of storing the data in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for the general idea. You'll need to tweak it to work with your database and data. I would advise avoiding doing it this way if you can, and adjusting your database to relate MenuItems to their respective headers.

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user","password","database", "3306"); 
    $query = "SELECT id, title, type FROM tbl_name";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $array1 = array();
    $currentHeading = "undefined";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if($row['type'] == 'MenuHeader') {
            $array1[$row['title']] = array();
            $currentHeading = $row['title'];
        } else {
            $array1[$currentHeading][] = $row['title'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: THanks i will only be able to test this now next week.